# How to extend AdonisJS Ally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, adonis.js

I tried to extend with Tumblr provider on Ally, from AdonisJS.

```
{ OAuthException: E_OAUTH_TOKEN_EXCHANGE: oauth_signature does not match expected value 
    at Function.tokenExchangeException (C:\Users\Maxence\Documents\Projets\test-project\node_modules@adonisjs\ally\src\Exceptions\index.js:36:19)
    at Tumblr.parseProviderError (C:\Users\Maxence\Documents\Projets\test-project\node_modules@adonisjs\ally\src\Schemes\OAuth.js:135:30)
    at client.getOAuthAccessToken (C:\Users\Maxence\Documents\Projets\test-project\node_modules@adonisjs\ally\src\Schemes\OAuth.js:189:32)
    at C:\Users\Maxence\Documents\Projets\test-project\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth.js:465:22
    at passBackControl (C:\Users\Maxence\Documents\Projets\test-project\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth.js:397:13)
    at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\Maxence\Documents\Projets\test-project\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth.js:409:9)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:165:20) 
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12) 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19) 
  original: { statusCode: 401, data: ‘oauth_signature does not match expected value’ } 
}
```

The Github repository is: https://github.com/pirmax/adonis-ally

Thanks to help me.